# how to log request and response in asp.net webapi as a text file on daily basis?

Tags: logging, asp.net-web-api2

I need to log the requests and responses in a text file using asp.net webAPI. provide with good simple example. I heard about using delegate handler we can achieve it as below.

```
public class LogRequestAndResponseHandler : DelegatingHandler
{
    protected override async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(
        HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        //logging request body
        string requestBody = await request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        Trace.WriteLine(requestBody);

        //let other handlers process the request
        return await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken)
            .ContinueWith(task =>
                {
                    //once response is ready, log it
                    var responseBody = task.Result.Content;
                    Trace.WriteLine (responseBody);

                    return task.Result;
                });
    }
}
```

but how to save request and response in a text file on daily basis. Provide with good simple example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if what you wanted something like this, though you may tweak as needed:

```
public class LogRequestAndResponseHandler : DelegatingHandler
{
    protected override async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(
        HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        //logging request body
        string requestBody = await request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        Trace.WriteLine(requestBody);

        //let other handlers process the request
        return await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken)
            .ContinueWith(task =>
                {
                    var responseBody = task.Result.Content;
                    Trace.WriteLine (responseBody);

                    // Write Text File. If file exists, appends. If file doesn't exist, creates.
                    string today = DateTime.Now.toString();
                    System.IO.StreamWriter StreamWriter1 = new System.IO.StreamWriter(Server.MapPath(today + ".txt"), true);
                    StreamWriter1.WriteLine(responseBody);
                    StreamWriter1.Close();

                    return task.Result;
                });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Yushell:
You need to check if Result.Content has a value, because an OPTIONS call to the API does NOT return a body and the code will fail.

Fix:

```
if (task.Result.Content != null)
{
    var responseBody = task.Result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
    ...
}
```